# How to get shell script to wait for pkg to finish installing

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to run a script that will mount a dmg, open a pkg, and then unmount.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Mounting Volume"
hdiutil attach -quiet "/path/to/DMG"
echo "Open pkg"
open /Volumes/DMG/pkg
echo "Unmounting volume"
hdiutil detach -quiet /Volumes/DMG
exit 0
```

This is what I have so far.

I want the script to be able to wait for the pkg to finish installing and then unmount. The reason I'm using open instead of installer is because sudo requires standard input but I'm running the script elsewhere where the user does not have access to the standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-W` flag for the `open` command.  From the man page: "Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited."

Comment: Works but takes a long time, at least 30 seconds, before it exits.

Comment: Oh my damn, I'm not smart. I had sleep 50 after the command because I was testing something out and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `wait` command. You just need to add `wait` command when you want to waits program before the execute other commands.

More information:
http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html